# Esper: "time_order" seems not working

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper, epl

I'm using Esper (the event processing engine), the EPL query is:

```
select * from Event.ext:time_order(timestamp_event, 10000 minutes) where duration > 10
```

But the output is not ordered by "timestamp_event":

```
id int = 1, timestamp_event= 1412686800000, duration = 30
id int = 4, timestamp_event= 1412685900000, duration = 70
id int = 2, timestamp_event= 1412688600000, duration = 45
id int = 3, timestamp_event= 1412689500000, duration = 60
id int = 5, timestamp_event= 1412636400000, duration = 15
```

Why does not the "time_order(timestamp_event, 10000 minutes)" instruction work?

I think the problem is on Esper configuration, let's consider a simple query:

```
select * from Event.win:time(10 sec) order by id_event
```

This is the code of the "upate" method of the UpdateListener:

```
 public void update(EventBean[] newEvents, EventBean[] oldEvents) {
     EventBean event = newEvents[0];
     System.out.println("id int = " + event.get("id_event") + ", timestamp_event = " +  ((Long)event.get("timestamp_event")).toString());
```

But the output is non ordered by "id_event"!

```
id event = 1, timestamp_event = 1412686800000
id event = 4, timestamp_event = 1412687700000
id event = 2, timestamp_event = 1412687100000
id event = 3, timestamp_event = 1412687400000
id event = 5, timestamp_event = 1412688000000
```

It seems neither the "order by" instruction doesn't work, how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to select rstream as the events leaving are ordered and not events entering. See http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.0.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#view-time-order

Comment: Adding "rstream" the output is the same, is there a way to pass to Esper ordered event by timestamp?

Comment: Why don't you review the regression tests for time_order and see where your code and the regression code are different. Link is http://svn.codehaus.org/esper/esper/trunk/esper/src/test/java/com/espertech/esper/regression/view/TestViewTimeOrder.java

Answer (score 0):

You need to define some sort of time or length constrain. Your statement is simply returning all the entering events into the time_order window.

A statement like this for example would give you all the events in the right order, every 1 minute:

```
select * from Event.ext:time_order(timestamp_event, 10000 minutes)
where duration > 10 output snapshot every 1 minute
```

Or, you could define a data window and insert events into it like this:

```
create window OrderedEvents.ext:time_order(timestamp_event, 10000 minutes) as select * from Event;
insert into OrderedEvents select * from Event;
```

You can then use ad-hoc queries against it, and they will return the events in the correct order (although you could achieve the same with a `win:time(10000 minutes)` and adding an `order by timestamp_event` to your ad-hoc query).

Comment: I've edited the initial post with further details, it seems that neither the "order by" command doesn't work!

Comment: `Order by` will not work this way, because you are still selecting the input stream and you will still get each event as you insert it. Try `select * from Event.win:time(10 sec) order by id_event output snapshot every 10 seconds`.